# filepicker.io widget doesn't work if inserted after DOM load

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm just getting integrated with filepicker.io, and I'm using the very first example they provide with a drag-drop widget.

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop"/>
```

If already present in the html when the page loads, the custom input converts correctly.  However if you add one to the page dynamically later, all you get is a featureless default input:

```
// Inserts generic featureless text input
$('#some_div').html('<input type="filepicker-dragdrop"/>');
```

Is there a way to force filepicker to reprocess the DOM and convert newly inserted widgets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use the constructWidget call on the dom element when it's created and inserted into the DOM. See https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-programming

Comment: How does one setup the OnSuccess callback when initializing via this method?

Comment: You'll likely want the onchange event handler, which can be set at any time, before or after the constructWidget call.